# Implementing if statements

Tags: turing-complete

I created my own programming language that compiles down to Turing Machine instructions and I was wondering how to implement `if(a>b) do _ end`. Here's the definition of the language(also available [here](https://github.com/ruler501/utm))

Variables are dynamically allocated at any width so can have arbitrarily large integers

Each line can do one of three things, it can call a function(which modifies it's argument), start a while loop(which is really more of a for loop), or assign a variable.

The available functions are `incr`(Increment by one, can overflow), `decr`(Decrement by one, can overflow), `pop`(Remove the last digit from a variable), `first`(Changes the most significant 0 in a variable to 1), and `frost`(changes the most significant 1 to a zero).

A while loop has the following syntax,

```
while a <func> {
    _
}
```

Basically every time it loops it does `<func>` to `a` till error condition. The error conditions are as follows, `incr` and `first` has all 1's, `decr` and `frost` has all 0's, `pop` removes the last digit. After a while loop with `incr` or `frost` all bits of the looping variable will be 0, opposite with `first` and `decr`. While loops have to end on a function call, and they delete all variables contained within after each run.

Assignment can do a few different things based on the syntax. `a=b` means copy variable `b` into the space owned by variable `a` if `b` is longer than `a` this causes undefined behavior unless `a` is the latest variable created. `a=b,5` assigns `b` to `a` with five padding bits(set to zero) to the left, again overflows cause undefined behavior unless `a` is the latest variable created. `a=a,0` zeroes out `a`. Finally `a=5,3` will assign `5 % 2**3` to `a` in 3 bits.

Now I can implement `if(a != 0) do _ end` with

```
while a decr {
    _
    t=0,1
    while a incr {
        incr(t)
    }
    incr(t)
}
```

My question is how can I implement the other if statements, like `if(a==b)`, `if(a!=b)`, and `if(a>b)`

And as a secondary question is this language Turing Complete, I believe so based on this answer [Are there minimum criteria for a programming language being Turing complete?](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/995/31186). I know the language satisfies 1 through 5, but I'm not sure about 6.

Answer (score 0):

(please let me know if i've assumed wrong about the loop or incr/decr behavior, that would alter my answer)

Your original code for `if(a!=0)` appears to loop forever. As it is, it's doing `while(a) do _ end` because it either loops indefinitely or not at all. Lastly `t` would not exist outside of the loop and does not appear to be utilized inside it, even though it looks like the value you're trying to capture (true/false on the comparison).

You don't have a comment syntax so i'll throw in `// comment` / c-style comments where needed.

Maybe something like this...

### if (a > 0) do _ end

```
// if (a > 0) do _ end
_a = a
while _a decr {
    // overflow iif _a= 0
    _ // do something
    _a = 0
    frost( _a ) // only function calls at end of loops
}
```

### if (a == 0) do _ end

```
// if (a == 0) do _ end
_a = a
result = 1,1
while _a decr {
    // overflow iif _a= 0
    _a = 0
    frost( result ) // only function calls at end of loops
}
while result decr {
    // overflow iif result = 0
    _ // do something
    frost( result ) // exit loop
}
```

The pattern is straightforward for a non-zero check as you've noticed - decrement it, and if you didnt overflow (underflow technically) then you're dealing with something that was 1 or greater. Trick is exiting the `while`, which you can do by using a decr test and setting the variable being tested to 0 upon exit. For this, your `frost` function is suitable because for a target variable of 0 it leaves the result unmodified, and a target of 1 becomes 0 such as in `result`'s usage.

Your documentation says that a function must mark the end of a loop, not an assignment or another loop, but your own examples are inconsistent with this, just to note.

I'm making an example for the remaining test conditions: `a > b` and `a == b`; the others can be derived from just these two and logical inversion / not operator, which you've seen in the above using `result`.

### if (a == b) do _ end

```
// if( a == b ) do _ end
a_cond = a
b_cond = b
// step 1: a_cond = a - b
while b_cond decr {
    decr(a_cond)
}
// step 2: if (a_cond == 0)
result = 1,1
while a_cond decr {
    // overflow iif a_cond = 0
    a_cond = 0
    frost( result ) // only function calls at end of loops
}
while result decr {
    // overflow iif result = 0
    _ // do something
    frost( result ) // exit loop
}
```

### if (a > b) do _ end

WIP. will be similar to (a==b) case